# CardView background colour is trimmed

Tags: android, background-color, android-cardview, cornerradius

I have set the corner radius of CardView to 50 dp to get the roundest corner.  But in some phones (I have seen in android 8) the card background colour is getting trimmed. Although the shadow/card elevation is rounded but the background colour is not.  What might be going wrong here ? 
Thanks in advance.

[image: marked views are cardviews]

Comment: Post your code pls

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a corner radius of `50dp` use the `shapeAppearanceOverlay` attribute to define a corner with `50%`:

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ButtomShape50"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/...."
        ...>
```

with:

```
<style name="ButtomShape50">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Programmatically you can do:

```
cardView.setShapeAppearanceModel(cardView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
            .toBuilder()
            .setAllCorners(new RoundedCornerTreatment()).setAllCornerSizes(new RelativeCornerSize(0.5f))
            .build());
```

Just a note about new `RelativeCornerSize(0.5f)`: It changed in `1.2.0-beta01`. Before it was `new RelativeCornerSize(50)`).

In your case you can also use a `FloatingActionButton` or a `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` without using the `CardView`.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ButtomShape50"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  But do you have anything for CardView widget ?  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView   Also hoe to do this dynamically without using any resource?

Comment: The `MaterialCardView` extends the `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` and it is provided by Google in the official Material Components Library. What do you mean dinamically? It is a static resources but you can do it also programmatically.

Comment: Yes I want to do this programmatically.  How to do that ?  And I don't want to use static resource file.  Everything should contain in the java file

Comment: Thank you. Your example works but since I am not using material theme I cannot use this. Anything for appCompat ? And I can create circle buttons using Floating buttons. Is custom background drawable the best option? Can we not use CardView to achieve this?

Comment: Which library are you using for the Fab?

Comment: I am using `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton` but it doesn't give me any exception. But when I use MaterialCardView it  tells me to change the theme

Comment: @dhir Check the [doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme).This library requires a Material Components theme or a Bridge theme.

Answer (score 2):

Setting android:outlineProvider="none" on CardView in xml fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `android:background` for the background color of the cardview? You should use `app:cardBackgroundColor`.

Comment: I am using app:cardBackgroundColor still having this issue.